# ASP.NET get whole object from appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, appsettings

If I have the following setup, is there a way to request the settings from within `Program.cs`.

`appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Settings": {
    "UseMemory": false,
    "Cors": {
      "Origins": "*",
      "Headers": "*",
      "Methods": "*"
    }
  }
}
```

Settings models:

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public bool? UseMemory { get; set; }
    public CorsSettings? Cors { get; set; }
}

public class CorsSettings
{
    public required string Origins { get; set; }
    public required string Headers { get; set; }
    public required string Methods { get; set; }
}
```

These were my attempts but the settings were always `null` (inside `Program.Main`)

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("Settings");
builder.Services.Configure<Models.AppSettings>(appSettings);
...
var settings = builder.Configuration.Get<Models.AppSettings>(); // { UseMemory: null, Cors: null }
```

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var settings = builder.Configuration.GetValue<Models.AppSettings>("Settings"); // null
var settingsText = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Settings"); // null
```

This "works" but I was hoping to find a way to get all the settings in a single tidy object:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var settingsText = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings").GetValue<string>("UseMemory"); // false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should do the trick.

```
var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<AppSettings>();
```

The QuickWatch window in Visual Studio shows the expected property values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked, on a slightly unrelated note, would you recommend I have all the properties for the settings as `required` or `?` (ideally they will always be defined the json)

Comment: Personal opinion, l would keep closest to the real world setup/expectation and have them required.

Comment: Optionally, but maybe overkill, you might foresee additional startup validation; see e.g https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-dotnet-6/